# Why does this flipallbits with XOR print like OR?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Here I am trying to implement the XOR (^) to flip all the bits in the number. But for some reason, it prints out all 1's as if the XOR (^) was in fact an OR (|). I can't seem to understand why. I took a look at operator precedence but I don't see how that would really make a difference here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void flipallbits(int x) {
  int i;
  for( i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    if( x ^ 1 << i ) {
      printf("1");
    } else {
      printf("0");
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  int num = 6541;
  flipallbits(num);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x ^= ~0; // too short to be submitted
```

Answer (score 1):

`x ^ 1 << i` is the same as `x ^ (1 << i)`.  So on each iteration of your loop, you're flipping a different bit.  But your test is simply checking that the result is non-zero; this is always true, because your input value has more than one bit set.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  If you simply want to print all the bits in turn, you want `x & 1 << i`.

Comment: If the bit value is

    01110

I want to print

    10001

I thought this could be done with XOR (^)?